# Can't change button href dynamically in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to access to a controller when clicking on a button. The fact is, i need to change the url of the button dynamically.

```
<p:button styleClass="btn-openHtml" href="#{data.htmlRenderUrl}" value="button html" target="_blank"></p:button>
```

The href property isn't updated when my bean's property changes. How can i make it so the value of href is updated when data.htmlRenderUrl is changed?

Comment: You should use ajax process and update attributes to clearly indicate when and what should be updated as the result of an event.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Answer (score 0):

you have to update the button with ajax.
when you update the property in your bean:

```
...
htmlRenderUrl = "/home";
//update your button
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("button-id");
...
```